# Hp N54L Proliant microserver network driver (Windows 10)

Tags: windows, windows-10, drivers, ethernet, hp-proliant

Hoping someone can shed some light on an issue i am having after the Windows 10 upgrade.

Everything on my HTPC is running 100% apart from the network (Ethernet) , wifi works fine via a dongle however i have run this cabled previously for streaming quality.

Since the upgrade it's not picking up and network over cable, the device manager says "Broadcom NetXtreme Gigabit Ethernet" but there is no connection.

Anyone aware of an updated driver , or anything else I can try.

PS Windows says the best driver is loaded.
I actually cant find any drivers on HP's site for this server either!

Thanks

Comment: Note that latest drivers for Broadcom NICs might be labelled as coming from QLogic.

Answer (score 8):

I had exactly the same issue, and after hours of trial and errors I finally fixed it.

Basically, I had to update the BIOS of my HP Proliant N40L to the latest version. The name of the update is called "SP64420.exe".
You can download the application from that page : http://www.msdonkey.com/server/bios-for-hp-proliant-microserver-g7-n54l/

Basically, you have to install/extract "SP64420.exe", that will normally put some files in the folder C:\SWSetup\SP64420 by default.
Then you have to find a usb drive, the smallest you can find, like 256mo will do. And then run C:\SWSetup\SP64420\USB Key\HPQUSB.exe to install that new BIOS on the flash drive. Depending on the size of the usb flash drive, it may take a few seconds, of maybe a few minutes.
Once this is done, you can just stop your server, insert the flash drive, and start the server. You will see the BIOS upgrade process running, it's just taking a couple of seconds, and then it will display a prompt C:/.
After that, you are a winner. Stop the server, remove the flash drive, and start the server.
Normally the network will magically be working again.

Comment: Thanks !!!  I shall try this tonight ! much appreciated !

Comment: This worked but I had to take an addition step. In the BIOS reapply the Optimal Settings and then it should be 100%

Comment: This worked for me too! N40L successfully upgraded to windows 10 (runs at 1080p native which it didnt on the previous windows server OS too - dont know if this was a result of the update or latest drivers in windows 10). Thanks!

Comment: This worked for me. Note that it is generally *extremely unadvisable* to install any drivers or BIOS from 3rd party sites. However, HPE apparently does not provide these drivers themselves (which is mindblowing to me), so desperate times may call for desperate measures. If you download this file, right-click it, hit Properties, then hit Digital Signatures, then hit Details, then hit View Certificate. You should see that it is issued to Hewlett-Packard Company by Verisign. For me, this was enough to give me some peace of mind that this file was the real deal, but run this file at your own risk.